# Problems with appscript conditional statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-sheets, google-apps-script, conditional-statements

I have a sheet that has radio buttons in 1 row from columns D to I. In columns B and C there are 2 checkboxes that I am using as a tally to increase and decrease values in different cells. What I want to acheive is, when a radio button is selected and is true(when a checkbox is checked), the increasing and decresing buttons/checkboxes change their location to increment and decrement the value at that location.
My problem is when I format the conditional statements, the increasing and decreasing buttons don't work. Help would be very much appreciated, I am new to coding so sometimes the syntax can be confusing. Below is what I have tried.

```
const RADIO_COLUMNS = ["D","E","F","G","H","I"];

function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const row = e.range.rowStart;
  const col = e.range.columnStart;
  const val = sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue();

  const colLetter = String.fromCharCode(64 + col);

  if (val == true && RADIO_COLUMNS.includes(colLetter)) {
    RADIO_COLUMNS.filter(column => column !== colLetter)
      .forEach(column => sheet.getRange(column + row).uncheck());
  }
  //if (!e) throw "Do not run from editor";
    if (RADIO_COLUMNS['D']='TRUE'){
   incrementAndDecrementD(e);
    } 
    else if (RADIO_COLUMNS['E']='TRUE') {
       incrementAndDecrementE(e);
    }
    else if (RADIO_COLUMNS['F']='TRUE') {  
      incrementAndDecrementF(e);
    }
//if radio buttons true then function incrementandDecrement(e)
}

}

function incrementAndDecrementD(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;

  if (src.getName() != "b" || r.columnStart < 2 || r.columnStart > 3) return;

  let out;
  if (r.columnStart == 2){
    out = r.offset(0,2);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()+1)
  } else {
    out = r.offset(0,1);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()-1)
  }

  r.setValue("FALSE");
}

function incrementAndDecrementE(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;

  if (src.getName() != "b" || r.columnStart < 2 || r.columnStart > 3) return;

  let out;
  if (r.columnStart == 2){
    out = r.offset(0,3);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()+1)
  } else {
    out = r.offset(0,2);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()-1)
  }

  r.setValue("FALSE");
}

function incrementAndDecrementF(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;

  if (src.getName() != "b" || r.columnStart < 2 || r.columnStart > 3) return;

  let out;
  if (r.columnStart == 2){
    out = r.offset(0,4);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()+1)
  } else {
    out = r.offset(0,3);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()-1)
  }

  r.setValue("FALSE");
}

function incrementAndDecrementG(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;

  if (src.getName() != "b" || r.columnStart < 2 || r.columnStart > 3) return;

  let out;
  if (r.columnStart == 2){
    out = r.offset(0,5);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()+1)
  } else {
    out = r.offset(0,4);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()-1)
  }

  r.setValue("FALSE");
}

function incrementAndDecrementH(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;

  if (src.getName() != "b" || r.columnStart < 2 || r.columnStart > 3) return;

  let out;
  if (r.columnStart == 2){
    out = r.offset(0,6);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()+1)
  } else {
    out = r.offset(0,5);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()-1)
  }

  r.setValue("FALSE");
}

function incrementAndDecrementI(e){
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;

  if (src.getName() != "b" || r.columnStart < 2 || r.columnStart > 3) return;

  let out;
  if (r.columnStart == 2){
    out = r.offset(0,7);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()+1)
  } else {
    out = r.offset(0,6);
    out.setValue(out.getValue()-1)
  }   

  r.setValue("FALSE");
}
```

Comment: You might want to use an installable trigger to start with atleast otherwise you may be bumping up against the 30 ssecond time limit for a simple trigger